# Problem with passing env variables from GitHub Actions to Docker container

Tags: bash, docker, docker-compose, github-actions

I have an app which consists of 3 services:

- DB
- Backend
- Frontend

I made a simple CI/CD via GitHub Actions through my self-hosted runner (a docker-in-docker service):

```
# .github/workflows/main.yml

name: CI/CD Pipeline
on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]

jobs:
  continuous-integration:
    runs-on: [self-hosted, linux, ARM64]
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3    
  continuous-deployment:
    runs-on: [self-hosted, linux, ARM64]
    needs: [continuous-integration]
    if: github.ref == 'refs/heads/main'
    env:
      PROTOCOL: ${{ secrets.PROTOCOL }}
      HOST: ${{ secrets.HOST }}
      PORT: ${{ secrets.PORT }}
    steps:
      - name: stop containers
        run: ./scripts/stop.sh
      - name: rebuild containers
        run: docker compose build
      - name: up containers
        run: ./scripts/run.sh -m prod
```

Here is part of my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
...
  backend:
    container_name: backend
    build: ./backend
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      - PROTOCOL=${PROTOCOL}
      - HOST=${HOST}
      - PORT=${PORT}
    ...
```

In my `./scripts/run.sh` I run: `docker container build`, but my containers can't get secret env variables from GitHub runner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, according to the discussion:
https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/49608
I had to put `environment: *environment_name*`to the body of the job; otherwise, secrets won't be visible.